# How to pass JWT authorization bearer token in nifi using JettyWebSocketClient

Tags: jwt, token, apache-nifi

How to pass authorization bearer JWT token in nifi using JettyWebSocketClient version 1.12.0 ?
Can not see any property to add the token for secure websocket connection...
Tried to add a custom property using "+" but the websocket client gets invalid with error message that the property is not supported.

Tried passing JWT token in the password property, but always get 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JWT token as a property on the `InovkeHTTP` processor, but you need to make sure the token is stored within the attributes of the flowfile.

I generate the JWT token using a script and then use the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor to fetch the value and add it to the attributes of the flowfile

[image: InvokeHTTP]
[image: Flow API]
[image: EvaluateJsonPath]

Comment: how does your script for creation of the JWT looks like?
I think it should have the parameters "Algorithm", "Payload" and "Private key"?